# Can see JSON data in a form in Mozilla but not in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Here is the [Updated Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/1yfySvtSUaDxaipf9xPA?p=preview).

I am trying to load a simple JSON file into a form using Angular js. But I am not seeing any data in the text boxes in Chrome but I can see in Mozilla. For chrome I am getting below error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/hp/Desktop/site/site.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Where am I going wrong?

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
  <title>Hello</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>

  <script>
   myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
   myApp.controller('myController', function($scope,$http){
   $http.get('site.json').success(function(response){
        $scope.myData=response;
     });
    });
  </script>

  </head>
 <body ng-controller="myController">

   <div ng-repeat="data in myData">
      <input type="text" name="">{{data.siteno}}
      <input type="text" name="">{{data.sitename}}
   </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Do you have somewhere `ng-controller="myController"`? Also, you are putting your `{{data.siteno}}` behind your textbox, maybe you mean `<input type="text" ng-model="data.siteno" />`? Besides that, how does your json look like? I can imagine that you should do something like `$scope.myData = response.someVariable;`

Comment: can you check in console whether you are getting json data in your response first.. fiddle link would be fine to solve this.

and yes @devqon mentioned it right Do u have defined controller somewhere in HTML

Comment: @devqon sorry had not formatted properly so missed the ng-controller. but you can see it now. will post my json data too.

Comment: @Krishna9960 Checked console. 2 errors I am getting. 1- Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. 2- Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined..Have checked it and location is correct. Besides have defined angular link before the script. I am not sure why still this error exists.

Comment: Take a look of this [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/OhviIzbkTfuD686QuuGz?p=preview)

Comment: so I missed this line $scope.myData = {}; right. Didnt define thsi object.

Comment: @gianlucatursi I see that plnkr is working but my code still gives the same 2 errors. 1- Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. 2- Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined..Have checked it and location is correct. Besides have defined angular link before the script. I am not sure why still this error exists.

Comment: yes your problem is that you don't define `$scope.myData = [];` than when angular compile the view you bind `undefined` and not a reference of the object. I have change other two things: 1) `ng-app="myApp"` in the body; 2)the name of the file from site to data;

Comment: I get this error now "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/hp/Desktop/site/site.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource." . Is it due to browser issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens since I am directly trying to run locally without any server. So easy solution for this would be to download a webserver plug in for chrome then you can run from the server url. I presume Mozilla must have already an inbuilt plug in which doesn't throw this error.

Answer (score 1):

## 1st error

You forgot to add `ng-app="myApp"`

```
ng-app="myApp"
```

## 2nd error

You were calling `site.json` but your file is named `data.json`

```
$http.get('data.json')
```

## 3rd error

You were putting `response` inside your object but the data are inside `response.data`

```
$scope.myData=response.data;
```

---

## Solution

Here is your updated [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/L5HogPaWzDqFVq3nj9Um?p=preview)

***Note :*** You should use `.then(function(resp){...}, function(err){...});` instead of `success()` and `error()` methods

Comment: Are you sure about the first 2 errors? Did I miss ng-app in my code? In plnkr I did change name to "data.json" but in my code it is same "site.json". About the third error it still works with $scope.myData=response

Comment: I see your plnkr work but when I include it in my code I still get same 2 errors i.e 1- Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. 2- Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined..Have checked it and location is correct. Besides have defined angular link before the script. I am not sure why still this error exists. Is it something to do with crome?

Comment: `ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` : check the path to your file. Angular is not defined because you did not add the script

Comment: @HebleV If you want better help, please provide a plunkr/Jsfiddle that reprodruce your errors

Comment: This is the plnkr  "https://plnkr.co/edit/1yfySvtSUaDxaipf9xPA?p=preview" and so the code I used. it works but in my browser i get those 2 erros which i mentioned it above. Yes location is correct all are in one single folder. So does it have something to do with browser chrome?

Comment: And yes I have added the script too.

Comment: This plunkr does not reproduce your error. Try your code on another browser. See the console for errors

Comment: I tried in mozilla. I am getting this error "The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol".

Comment: @HebleV Please check this error. You are certainly missing a tag somewhere

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135244/discussion-between-heblev-and-weedoze).

Comment: It works in mozilla but chrome gives this error "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/hp/Desktop/site/site.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource." Is the any way to play around?